# CSS text over image hover does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to get a photo description happening when you hover over the image.  This sounds like an easy task but I can't get it to work. I've tried several different methods and none work or the pop up shows up all over the place or messes up my divs.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="mainimg">
        <a href="url" target="_blank">
            <img src="'thumbnail">
        </a>
        <span class="text">
            <p>'item.comment'</p>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="pfooter">
        <img src="avatar">
        <a href="userhome" target="_"blank">username</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#box {
    width:180px;
    height:260px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#box .mainimg img {
    width: 160px;
    height 160px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border:1px solid #;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
#box .mainimg span.text {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table;
    height: 150px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 150px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}
#box mainimg:hover span.text {
    opacity: 1;
}
#box .pfooter img {
    width: 50px;
    height: auto;
    position;
    absolute;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    float: left;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#box .pfooter {
    height: 50px;
    width: 160px;
    font-size:0.75em;
}
#box .pfooter a {
    color: #808080;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: you're missing a dot before mainimg, here #box mainimg:hover span.text

Comment: As Juan C said, you're missing `.` before `mainimg:hover `. You also got `"` before `blank` in target. `<p></p>` shouldn't be placed in span either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a dot on one of your `.mainimg` selectors

Here is what you want: [**Working CodePen demo**](http://codepen.io/ryanw/pen/FIhCk/)

```
#box {
    width:180px;
    height:260px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    position: relative;
}
#box .mainimg img {
    width: 160px;
    height 160px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border:1px solid #;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
#box .mainimg .text {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table;
    height: 142px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 152px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    border:1px solid #;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 4px;
}
#box .mainimg:hover .text {
    opacity: 1;
}
#box .pfooter img {
    width: 50px;
    height: auto;
    position;
    absolute;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    float: left;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#box .pfooter {
    height: 50px;
    width: 160px;
    font-size:0.75em;
}
#box .pfooter a {
    color: #808080;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Looks like you were doing fine and just need to adjust the text box position. Add `position: relative;` to `#box` is a good start. I also rounded the corners.

See my [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/ryanw/pen/FIhCk/) linked above for more tweaks.

Comment: I tried your example, it looks great.. except same problem as the guy below.. my hovers all appear on the top left of the page.   Im creating several rows of images, and all these hovers appear at the top of the doc.   I've played with the "position:" setting to no avail.

Comment: @BrandN00b You need to set the position of the parent (**#box**) to `relative`, and the **.text** to `absolute`. If you don't set the parent to relative, then the absolute positioning is relative to the doc, not the parent container, and will show up at the top left of the doc.

Comment: @BrandN00b see my updated [Demo](http://codepen.io/ryanw/pen/FIhCk/) to see how it works with multiple images on the page.

Comment: YES! i was missing 'position: relative;' in #box.  Only issue left is the hover doesnt align perfectly, its a little bit off. plus some comments are so long they make the box super long. But I think i can play around with that. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The are three problems

1. is that you don't have a `.` before `mainimg:hover`

   ```
   #box .mainimg:hover span.text {
      opacity: 1;
   }
   ```
2. you need to add some value to the `top` and `left` in the `#box .mainimg span.text`

   ```
   #box .mainimg span.text {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   color: white;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: table;
   height: 150px;
   left: 34px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 12px;
   width: 150px;
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
   -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
   -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
   transition: opacity 500ms;
   }
   ```
3. Some of your HTML was incorrect `<a href="userhome" target="_"blank">username</a>` should be `<a href="userhome" target="_blank">username</a>`

I fixed those three problems in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tj9ew/)

Comment: Very helpful, however the hover for all images (this is an array of images) shows up on the top left of the screen. Very far away.. I've played with some position tags but still no luck.

Comment: Also,would be nice to have the edges rounded on the hover, just like in the image.. is that even possible?

Comment: @BrandN00b  I did all that (fixing position and rounding corners) on my demo in my answer yesterday

Comment: I've copied your example. Does it in chrome and firefox.  Could anything else be making the hover appear in the top left?